# Hosting multiple NativeViews in a Flutter app

Tags: flutter, flutter-native-view

I'm doing the good old native view hosting (codes at the end, which is basically copied from Flutter website) for a video chat app. I want to show video feed of each user in one of these.

For that I tried to pass different `creationParams`, but it seems only one `View` can exist at a time; no new  "view creation" occur after the first one.

Do I have to `register` each view in advance, passing different `viewType` for each? Or is there a better way for having unknown number of `NativeView`s?

`Flutter`

```
const String viewType = '<platform-view-type>';
final Map<String, dynamic> creationParams = <String, dynamic>{};

switch (defaultTargetPlatform) {
  case TargetPlatform.android:
    return AndroidView(
      viewType: viewType,
      layoutDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      creationParams: creationParams,
      creationParamsCodec: const StandardMessageCodec(),
    );
  case TargetPlatform.iOS:
    return UiKitView(
      viewType: viewType,
      layoutDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      creationParams: creationParams,
      creationParamsCodec: const StandardMessageCodec(),
    );
  default:
    throw UnsupportedError('Unsupported platform view');
```

`iOS`

```
registrar.register(nativeViewFactory, withId: "<platform-view-type>")
```

`Android`

```
flutterPluginBinding.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory("<platform-view-type>", nativeViewFactory)
```

*Edit: This is how I tried to create different views by passing different params:*

`ViewFactory (android)`

```
class NativeViewFactory : PlatformViewFactory(StandardMessageCodec.INSTANCE) {
    private lateinit var selfVideoView: NativeView
    private val remoteVideoViews: MutableMap<String, NativeView> = HashMap()

    fun getSelfVideo(): NativeView {
        return selfVideoView
    }

    override fun create(context: Context?, viewId: Int, args: Any?): PlatformView {
        val creationParams = args as Map<String?, Any?>?
        return if (context != null) {
            val videoView = NativeView(context, viewId, creationParams)
            if (creationParams == null || creationParams.isEmpty()) {
                selfVideoView = videoView
            } else {
                val username = creationParams["username"] as String
                remoteVideoViews[username] = videoView

                /// ...
                /// Connect video feed of 'username' to videoView
                /// ...
            }
            videoView
        } else {
            throw IllegalStateException("Context is null")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify the exact question, pls? Because it's hard to understand what exactly you are looking for

Comment: For example I want to show two `NativeView`s in a column.

Comment: Thank you! Could you provide the code of your factory?